# Java Change Volume OSX

Tags: java, macos, volume, osx-mavericks

I am trying to change the volume on my mac running OSX Mavericks. I am currently using this code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/osascript -e 'set volume 15'");
```

But although I do not get any errors the volume does not change. I tried running the same command from terminal and it worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try: 
  String[] cmd = {"osascript", "-e","set volume 15"};
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

Comment: Maybe [OS X integration for Java](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/07-NativePlatformIntegration/NativePlatformIntegration.html) will help

Comment: In theory, you can also do `FloatControl volume = (FloatControl) AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(null).getControl(FloatControl.Type.VOLUME); volume.setValue(15);`  But I haven't tried it in OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `ProcessBuilder`, and set the three parts of the command (`osascript`, `-e` and `set volume 15`) as separate “words” in the command. Then you'll get Java to handle the correct quoting for you rather than trying to figure it out for yourself (which is a bit hard when dealing with arguments with spaces in).

The single quotes are a feature of the interactive shell, not of `osascript`.